# TypeError: Cannot call method 'then' of undefined in Nodejs Promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, callback, promise

Can you please explain what is wrong in this code below.

```
   var promise = fs.readFile(file);

   var promise2 = promise.then(function(data){
      var base64 = new Buffer(data, 'binary').toString('base64');
      res.end("success");
   }, function(err){
      res.end("fail");
   });
```

Its throwing error as `TypeError: Cannot call method 'then' of undefined`

Comment: `readFile` does not return a promise, why do you think it does?

Comment: I am trying for base64 encryption of file as you can see, but i am new to promises. Then what would be the ideal of handling this scenario?

Comment: @Mithun you pass in a callback as described [here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_options_callback) Also "but i am new to promises", maybe, but again, there is no promise involved here.

Comment: @Mithun: Have a look at [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create an Async function which returns a promise or use a promise library like [bluebird.js](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird)

**Vanilla JS**

```
 var promise = readFileAsync();
    promise.then( function(result) {
        // yay! I got the result.
    }, function(error) {
        // The promise was rejected with this error.
    }

    function readFileAsync()
    {
       var promise = new Promise.Promise();
       fs.readFile( "somefile.txt", function( error, data ) {
            if ( error ) {
                promise.reject( error );
            } else {
                promise.resolve( data );
            }
        });

        return promise;
    }
```

**With BlueBird.js**

```
 var Promise = require("bluebird"); 
 var fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require("fs"));

    fs.readFileAsync("myfile.json").then(JSON.parse).then(function (json) {
        console.log("Successful json");
    }).catch(SyntaxError, function (e) {
        console.error("file contains invalid json");
    }).catch(Promise.OperationalError, function (e) {
        console.error("unable to read file, because: ", e.message);
    });
```

Comment: Well, if you're using Bluebird, you should simply use `promsifyAll`

Answer (score 2):

[`readFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_options_callback) doesn't return a promise. The NodeJS by and large predates widespread use of promises and mostly uses simple callbacks instead.

To read the file, you pass in a simple callback, as this example from the documentation shows:

```
fs.readFile('/etc/passwd', function (err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(data);
});
```

There is a [`promisify-node` module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promisify-node) available that wraps standard NodeJS modules in a promise-enabled API. Example from its docs:

```
var promisify = require("promisify-node");
var fs = promisify("fs")
fs.readFile("/etc/passwd").then(function(contents) {
  console.log(contents);
});
```

I should emphasize that I don't know it and haven't used it, so I can't speak to how well it does its job. It appears to use [`nodegit-promise`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodegit-promise), a *"Bare bones Promises/A+ implementation with synchronous inspection"* rather than JavaScript's `Promise` (which is only fair; it predates JavaScript's `Promise` by a couple of years).